# delete from datatable jquery mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to delete row from data-table jquery together with sweetjs.

From some reason, I cant get ID of the row. constantly is id=12 (first row).

Then it goes to my controller, into POST method of Delete, but always with id=12 (first row) and then it breaks there, cause it can't find it in database.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t = $('.example').DataTable();
    $('.example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            t.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        alert('Row index: ' + t.row(this).index()); //just cheking my id's
    });
    $('#button').click(function () {
        if (t.row('.selected')[0].length == 0) {
            swal("Morate selektovati red u tabeli.", "Ova operacija nije dozvoljena.", "warning");
            return false;
        }
        //var t = $('#report').DataTable();
        swal({
            title: "Da li ste sigurni?",
            text: "Posle brisanja se ne mogu povratiti podaci.",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-warning',
            confirmButtonText: 'Da, obriši',
            cancelButtonText: "Odustani",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/AdeccoViews/Delete",
                        contentType: 'application/json;',
                        data: JSON.stringify({ id: t.row('.selected').data()[0] }),
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.boolResponse == true) {
                                t.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
                                swal("Obrisano!", "Veza između korisnika je obrisana!", "success");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (valid) {
                            //window.location.href = "/Views/ERROR";
                            swal("Došlo je do greške!", "Molimo vas da pokušate ponovo!", "error");
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    swal("Brisanje poništeno", "SalesActivity je i dalje tuuuuu", "info");
                }
            });
    });
});
```

`<button type="button" id="button">Delete</button>`

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        object obj;
        try
        {
            AdeccoView adeccoView = db.AdeccoViews.Find(id);
            db.AdeccoViews.Remove(adeccoView);
            db.SaveChanges();
            obj = new
            {
                boolResponse = true

            };
            return Json(obj);
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you generating the button? It would be far easier to just add the ID as a `data-` attribute (e.g. `<button data-id="@item.ID">` and get it using `var ID = $(this).data('id');` And there is no need to stringify the data and use `contentType: 'application/json;',`

Comment: @StephenMuecke wow! Great! I will try it. Do you have some example or link where I can read about it? I am student. Tnx. it cannot resolve the symbol. It looks like it cant see my model on the view page..

Comment: [jQuery.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Comment: I've tried, but now, for all buttons in table (delete) except for the first one, I cant do nothing :) tnx  anyway edit:on refresh, I can actually delete just first row. haha

Comment: Thats because you have used an `id` attribute for the button (so `$('#button').click(function () {` will only ever handle the first button because duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html). Change it to a `class="button"` and use `$('.button').click(function () {`

Comment: Yes, I recalled it that same id cannot be called twice..I've put class instead of id, but now even the first row cannot be called..button is unactive

Comment: It's working..I misspelled a dot. :) Thanks a lot! Only it's a little bit ugly that datatble wont update itself after deletion..

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: t.row('.selected').data()[0] }),
```

Your ajax is hard-coded to get the first row (`[0]`).

Or, this line is not actually working:

```
t.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

which is causing the first row (which was initially selected) to still have that class.

You can debug with Chrome debugging tools (F12) to break on this line and see what is being assigned to `id`.

Comment: I've inserted hidden columns. I found that solution on the Web. Tnx anyway for a hint. Will check. Yes I now for F12 debug tool :) that's how I realized that my ID's are not good.

Comment: If I leave just `data: JSON.stringify({ id: t.row('.selected').data()})` maybe it will be more reasonable?

Comment: I think setting a var id on the click would be more reliable. I don't think you need a data-id attribute. Just a javascript var to keep track of it.